# Make a 2 cell horizontal stack layout 50% of device screen width

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to make the image 50% the screen size on a Xamarin Forms project. I can't seem to find a definitive answer how I go about this. I came across an ancient blog post about Xamarin.Labs but not sure if this is still relevant.

**Option 1** is to try and make each child in the stacklayout 50%

```
var horizontalLayout = new StackLayout ();
horizontalLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;

//What do I add here?    

//add views to the view hierarchy
horizontalLayout.Children.Add (Photo ());
horizontalLayout.Children.Add (textLayout);
```

**Option 2** make the image width 50%

```
private Image Photo ()
{
    var image = new Image ();
    image.WidthRequest = ??;
    image.SetBinding (Image.SourceProperty, "Member.MemberPhoto");
    return image;
}
```

[image]

`textLayout` is also a stack layout which is to the right of the image

```
StackLayout textLayout = new StackLayout ();

textLayout.Children.Add (CompanyName ());
textLayout.Children.Add (SubCategory ());
textLayout.Children.Add (Address ());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Grid` as your outer container and specify a `ColumnDefinition` using a `GridLength` of 1 and `GridUnitType` of `Star` like so:-

```
Grid objGrid = new Grid()
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
};
objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
{
    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
});
objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
{
    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
});
```

Shown below is a full example with a `Button` that when clicked shows the image size being explicitly set to various values.

No matter if the image size is small, or larger than the 50% width area, it will keep the layout of the `Grid` keeping at the `50%` width.

**Example:-**

```
StackLayout objStackLayout = new StackLayout();

Grid objGrid = new Grid()
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
};
objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
{
    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
});
objGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
{
    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
});
objStackLayout.Children.Add(objGrid);


Image objImage = new Image()
{
    Source = ImageSource.FromFile(" {put some image here} "),
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
};
objGrid.Children.Add(objImage, 0,0);

Label objLabel = new Label();
objLabel.Text = "Some long text goes here.... blah blah blah.....    Some long text goes here.... blah blah blah.....    Some long text goes here.... blah blah blah.....    Some long text goes here.... blah blah blah.....    Some long text goes here.... blah blah blah.....    Some long text goes here.... blah blah blah.....    Some long text goes here.... blah blah blah.....    Some long text goes here.... blah blah blah.....    Some long text goes here.... blah blah blah.....   Some long text goes here.... blah blah blah..... ";
objGrid.Children.Add(objLabel, 1,0);


Button objButton = new Button();
objButton.Text = "Change Image Width"            ;
objButton.Clicked+=((o2,e2)=>
{
    if (objImage.WidthRequest == -1)
    {
        objImage.WidthRequest = 50;
    }
    else if (objImage.WidthRequest == 50)
    {
        objImage.WidthRequest = 150;
    }
    else if (objImage.WidthRequest == 150)
    {
        objImage.WidthRequest = 350;
    }
    else if (objImage.WidthRequest == 350)
    {
        objImage.WidthRequest = 50;
    }
});
objStackLayout.Children.Add(objButton);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I assume I can add a StackLayout to the right cell part of the grid rather than just a label?

Comment: @Rippo Yes, of course.  Add any View you want, and then add that to the Grid at a certain position and you'll be good to go.